# ! Package frenchb.ldf Error: frenchb requires babel v.3.9i

Tags: babel, french

I have this message error :
**! Package frenchb.ldf Error: frenchb requires babel v.3.9i.**
I hadn't it few days ago. I rebooted, reinstalled Miktex, reinstalled babel, rebuilt pdflatex.
Here is a minimal code and the log file.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

LOG FILE :

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2014.5.31) 31 MAY 2014 17:51
entering extended mode
**test_babel.tex
(C:\Users\myname\Desktop\test_babel\test_babel.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic,
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2013-05-26, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2013-05-26, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty"
Package: inputenc 2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\utf8.def"
File: utf8.def 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
Now handling font encoding OML ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OML
Now handling font encoding T1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding T1
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.dfu"
File: t1enc.dfu 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
defining Unicode char U+00AB (decimal 171)
defining Unicode char U+00BB (decimal 187)
defining Unicode char U+00BF (decimal 191)
defining Unicode char U+00C0 (decimal 192)
defining Unicode char U+00C1 (decimal 193)
defining Unicode char U+00C2 (decimal 194)
defining Unicode char U+00C3 (decimal 195)
defining Unicode char U+00C4 (decimal 196)
defining Unicode char U+00C5 (decimal 197)
defining Unicode char U+00C6 (decimal 198)
defining Unicode char U+00C7 (decimal 199)
defining Unicode char U+00C8 (decimal 200)
defining Unicode char U+00C9 (decimal 201)
defining Unicode char U+00CA (decimal 202)
defining Unicode char U+00CB (decimal 203)
defining Unicode char U+00CC (decimal 204)
defining Unicode char U+00CD (decimal 205)
defining Unicode char U+00CE (decimal 206)
defining Unicode char U+00CF (decimal 207)
defining Unicode char U+00D0 (decimal 208)
defining Unicode char U+00D1 (decimal 209)
defining Unicode char U+00D2 (decimal 210)
defining Unicode char U+00D3 (decimal 211)
defining Unicode char U+00D4 (decimal 212)
defining Unicode char U+00D5 (decimal 213)
defining Unicode char U+00D6 (decimal 214)
defining Unicode char U+00D8 (decimal 216)
defining Unicode char U+00D9 (decimal 217)
defining Unicode char U+00DA (decimal 218)
defining Unicode char U+00DB (decimal 219)
defining Unicode char U+00DC (decimal 220)
defining Unicode char U+00DD (decimal 221)
defining Unicode char U+00DE (decimal 222)
defining Unicode char U+00DF (decimal 223)
defining Unicode char U+00E0 (decimal 224)
defining Unicode char U+00E1 (decimal 225)
defining Unicode char U+00E2 (decimal 226)
defining Unicode char U+00E3 (decimal 227)
defining Unicode char U+00E4 (decimal 228)
defining Unicode char U+00E5 (decimal 229)
defining Unicode char U+00E6 (decimal 230)
defining Unicode char U+00E7 (decimal 231)
defining Unicode char U+00E8 (decimal 232)
defining Unicode char U+00E9 (decimal 233)
defining Unicode char U+00EA (decimal 234)
defining Unicode char U+00EB (decimal 235)
defining Unicode char U+00EC (decimal 236)
defining Unicode char U+00ED (decimal 237)
defining Unicode char U+00EE (decimal 238)
defining Unicode char U+00EF (decimal 239)
defining Unicode char U+00F0 (decimal 240)
defining Unicode char U+00F1 (decimal 241)
defining Unicode char U+00F2 (decimal 242)
defining Unicode char U+00F3 (decimal 243)
defining Unicode char U+00F4 (decimal 244)
defining Unicode char U+00F5 (decimal 245)
defining Unicode char U+00F6 (decimal 246)
defining Unicode char U+00F8 (decimal 248)
defining Unicode char U+00F9 (decimal 249)
defining Unicode char U+00FA (decimal 250)
defining Unicode char U+00FB (decimal 251)
defining Unicode char U+00FC (decimal 252)
defining Unicode char U+00FD (decimal 253)
defining Unicode char U+00FE (decimal 254)
defining Unicode char U+00FF (decimal 255)
defining Unicode char U+0102 (decimal 258)
defining Unicode char U+0103 (decimal 259)
defining Unicode char U+0104 (decimal 260)
defining Unicode char U+0105 (decimal 261)
defining Unicode char U+0106 (decimal 262)
defining Unicode char U+0107 (decimal 263)
defining Unicode char U+010C (decimal 268)
defining Unicode char U+010D (decimal 269)
defining Unicode char U+010E (decimal 270)
defining Unicode char U+010F (decimal 271)
defining Unicode char U+0110 (decimal 272)
defining Unicode char U+0111 (decimal 273)
defining Unicode char U+0118 (decimal 280)
defining Unicode char U+0119 (decimal 281)
defining Unicode char U+011A (decimal 282)
defining Unicode char U+011B (decimal 283)
defining Unicode char U+011E (decimal 286)
defining Unicode char U+011F (decimal 287)
defining Unicode char U+0130 (decimal 304)
defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)
defining Unicode char U+0132 (decimal 306)
defining Unicode char U+0133 (decimal 307)
defining Unicode char U+0139 (decimal 313)
defining Unicode char U+013A (decimal 314)
defining Unicode char U+013D (decimal 317)
defining Unicode char U+013E (decimal 318)
defining Unicode char U+0141 (decimal 321)
defining Unicode char U+0142 (decimal 322)
defining Unicode char U+0143 (decimal 323)
defining Unicode char U+0144 (decimal 324)
defining Unicode char U+0147 (decimal 327)
defining Unicode char U+0148 (decimal 328)
defining Unicode char U+014A (decimal 330)
defining Unicode char U+014B (decimal 331)
defining Unicode char U+0150 (decimal 336)
defining Unicode char U+0151 (decimal 337)
defining Unicode char U+0152 (decimal 338)
defining Unicode char U+0153 (decimal 339)
defining Unicode char U+0154 (decimal 340)
defining Unicode char U+0155 (decimal 341)
defining Unicode char U+0158 (decimal 344)
defining Unicode char U+0159 (decimal 345)
defining Unicode char U+015A (decimal 346)
defining Unicode char U+015B (decimal 347)
defining Unicode char U+015E (decimal 350)
defining Unicode char U+015F (decimal 351)
defining Unicode char U+0160 (decimal 352)
defining Unicode char U+0161 (decimal 353)
defining Unicode char U+0162 (decimal 354)
defining Unicode char U+0163 (decimal 355)
defining Unicode char U+0164 (decimal 356)
defining Unicode char U+0165 (decimal 357)
defining Unicode char U+016E (decimal 366)
defining Unicode char U+016F (decimal 367)
defining Unicode char U+0170 (decimal 368)
defining Unicode char U+0171 (decimal 369)
defining Unicode char U+0178 (decimal 376)
defining Unicode char U+0179 (decimal 377)
defining Unicode char U+017A (decimal 378)
defining Unicode char U+017B (decimal 379)
defining Unicode char U+017C (decimal 380)
defining Unicode char U+017D (decimal 381)
defining Unicode char U+017E (decimal 382)
defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)
defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)
defining Unicode char U+2018 (decimal 8216)
defining Unicode char U+2019 (decimal 8217)
defining Unicode char U+201A (decimal 8218)
defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)
defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)
defining Unicode char U+201E (decimal 8222)
defining Unicode char U+2030 (decimal 8240)
defining Unicode char U+2031 (decimal 8241)
defining Unicode char U+2039 (decimal 8249)
defining Unicode char U+203A (decimal 8250)
defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
)
Now handling font encoding OT1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OT1
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ot1enc.dfu"
File: ot1enc.dfu 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
defining Unicode char U+00B8 (decimal 184)
defining Unicode char U+00BF (decimal 191)
defining Unicode char U+00C5 (decimal 197)
defining Unicode char U+00C6 (decimal 198)
defining Unicode char U+00D8 (decimal 216)
defining Unicode char U+00DF (decimal 223)
defining Unicode char U+00E6 (decimal 230)
defining Unicode char U+00EC (decimal 236)
defining Unicode char U+00ED (decimal 237)
defining Unicode char U+00EE (decimal 238)
defining Unicode char U+00EF (decimal 239)
defining Unicode char U+00F8 (decimal 248)
defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)
defining Unicode char U+0141 (decimal 321)
defining Unicode char U+0142 (decimal 322)
defining Unicode char U+0152 (decimal 338)
defining Unicode char U+0153 (decimal 339)
defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)
defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)
defining Unicode char U+2018 (decimal 8216)
defining Unicode char U+2019 (decimal 8217)
defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)
defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)
)
Now handling font encoding OMS ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMS
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\omsenc.dfu"
File: omsenc.dfu 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
defining Unicode char U+00B6 (decimal 182)
defining Unicode char U+00B7 (decimal 183)
defining Unicode char U+2020 (decimal 8224)
defining Unicode char U+2021 (decimal 8225)
defining Unicode char U+2022 (decimal 8226)
)
Now handling font encoding OMX ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMX
Now handling font encoding U ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding U
defining Unicode char U+00A9 (decimal 169)
defining Unicode char U+00AA (decimal 170)
defining Unicode char U+00AE (decimal 174)
defining Unicode char U+00BA (decimal 186)
defining Unicode char U+02C6 (decimal 710)
defining Unicode char U+02DC (decimal 732)
defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
defining Unicode char U+2026 (decimal 8230)
defining Unicode char U+2122 (decimal 8482)
defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.sty"
Package: babel 2008/07/08 v3.8m The Babel package
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\bblopts.cfg"
File: bblopts.cfg 2006/07/31 v1.0 MiKTeX 'babel' configuration
)
(C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\babel-french\frenchb.ld
f
Language: frenchb 2014/04/18 v3.0c French support from the babel system
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def"
File: babel.def 2008/07/08 v3.8m Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count87
\U@D=\dimen103
)
! Package frenchb.ldf Error: frenchb requires babel v.3.9i.
(frenchb.ldf) Aborting here.
See the frenchb.ldf package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.116 {Please upgrade Babel!}
Please upgrade Babel!
)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def"
File: t1enc.def 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 43.
))
No file test_babel.aux.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 5.
! Package babel Error: You haven't loaded the option english yet.
See the babel package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.5 \begin{document}
You may proceed, but expect unexpected results
[1
{C:/Users/myname/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(C:\Users\myname\Desktop\test_babel\test_babel.aux
! Package babel Error: You haven't loaded the option english yet.
See the babel package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.2 \select@language{english}
You may proceed, but expect unexpected results
) )
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
928 strings out of 493921
9590 string characters out of 3147273
59987 words of memory out of 3000000
4274 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
4403 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
841 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
24i,4n,19p,181b,113s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\pk\ljfour\jknappen\ec\dpi
600\ecrm1000.pk>
Output written on test_babel.pdf (1 page, 2700 bytes).
PDF statistics:
14 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Looks like the classic MiKTeX issue: you've installed for multiple users, but have only updated the 'all users' part. Run the update system both in 'normal' and 'admin' mode.

Comment: It resolved the problem. thks

Comment: The OP solved the problem him/herself.